# Why what ever function I use in Anaconda 3 IDE from openpyxl goes into "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute" after run?

Tags: python, data-science, openpyxl, powerbi-desktop

So, I am playing around in with openpyxl because I want to automate a Excel huge file ( filter, delete rows, merge and stuff like that ) in another better Excel and cleaner so I can import it in PowerBi.
But anytime I use for ex. ws.insert_cols or rows or ws.merge_cells, goes after I hit save and run into this error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute" after run.
I use Anaconda3 and I have installed the lasted version of openpyxl.
Thanks a lot in advanced

[image]   I have tried updating the the openpyxl but it does not fix it.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include code as text and not as an image.

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=workbook#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.active " active - Get the currently active sheet or None" you just get None from that. It's not initialisation as your comment in the code suggests

Comment: from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter


'''ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Data"

ws.append(['Edi', 'Is', '20'])
wb.save('edi.xlsx')'''

wb = Workbook('edi.xlsx') #initializam un nou fisier de excel
ws = wb.active #initializam sheet ul default creat
ws.insert_rows(1)
ws.insert_rows(2)
wb.save('edi.xlsx')

Comment: Thanks, ewong. h4z3 I am not sure I get it right from what you tell me.

Comment: Please don't include the code in the comments but update the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.